# Hello all, first time trying to develop an android RSS APP and having 2 errors

Tags: java, android, rss

2 Questions:

First:cannot resolve symbol 'menu'

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);    
return true;
    }
```

Can I just delete this method?

Second:cannot resolve symbol 'action_settings'

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

My Strings.xml file codes:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My Application</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Action Settings</string>
</resources>
```

Tried Invalidate Caches/Restart.

Comment: Do you have a menu folder on your res ?

Comment: Those methods are for creating a Menu. If you don't want that menu, yes, you can delete the method. About the errors, you should check if you have a menu.xml in your res folder and the second one is the id of one of its items, no the string resource.

Comment: You can delete the two methods entirely, if you don't want to have menus on you application.

Comment: Thank you all, i just decided to delete these 2 methods. I do not have menu folder i believe its the reason.

Answer (score 0):

That code is autogenerated by the IDE.

Its used to create and manage the contextual menu of the app (Opens with the android menu button).

If you are not using the contextual menu just delete that code.

Or if you plan to use it take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/menus.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, i will just delete those method.